# JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: value is null

Tags: jboss, slf4j

Hi I am new to `JBoss` and trying to deploy my web application in `JBoss EAP 6`. The deployment is successful and while trying to access the application I am getting the below exception. I am using `logback` and `slf4j` for logging in my application. Can anyone help me find a solution for this

```
12:04:12,846 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 37270ms - Started 185 of 245 services (59 services are passive or on-demand)
12:19:32,799 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SynergyClient].[jsp]] (http-/127.0.0.1:9090-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: value is null
    at org.jboss.logmanager.MDC.put(MDC.java:58) [jboss-logmanager-1.5.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.5.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jMDCAdapter.put(Slf4jMDCAdapter.java:32)
    at org.slf4j.MDC.put(MDC.java:116) [slf4j-api-1.7.2.redhat-2.jar:1.7.2.redhat-2]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.insertIntoMDC(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:70) [logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49) [logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: value is null

Thats a pretty straight forward exception. My advise would be to debug the values one by one that are being passed to the JSP.

Your variable `value` is getting passed as null. Check to see that the name of the parameters match and that proper getter/setters exist against the correct parameter variable

Comment: Thanks Saif for the answer. But my jsp file doesn't have a variable named value in it. The same war file gets deployed and is working properly with glassfish and tomcat server.

Comment: Can you paste your SynergyClient.jsp file here ?